# Responsive background image Github deployment issue

Tags: css, github, responsive-design, background-image, materialize

Im having an issue where my responsive background image does not work on mobile after being deployed to Github.  The image looks correct the under google chrome inspect mobile tool, however when the live site is loaded on a mobile device the image covers the background but is zoomed in to the top left corner.

I am using materialize for the project but base css for the background image

Here is my current code for the background image

```
html {
  background: url(../assets/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And here is the live site:
https://connorbreault.dev/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Everything looks fine to me.Remember to use this piece of code

```
 overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Does this website show up with the full image when you load https://connorbreault.dev/ on a mobile device?  It shows a zoomed in version on my and my girlfriends devices.. Here is a link to the full image on unsplash https://unsplash.com/photos/zf3gwt5Rod0